# open ssh connection freezes

Tags: linux, ssh, tcl

I'm trying to open ssh connection with Tcl8.5 script with something like:

```
catch {set fh [open "|sshpass -p $password ssh $user@$ip" w+]} catch_output

if {[info exists fh] != 1} {
    puts "err - $catch_output"
    return 0
}
fconfigure $fh -buffering none -blocking 0

set i 0
while {1} {
    puts "iteration $i."
    set data [read -nonewline $fh]
    append input_sum $data                        

    puts -nonewline $data

    after 1000
    incr i
}
```

But the only text that I receive from the remote machine is:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-45-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
```

And this is where it hangs...
The variable `$i` helps to make sure that the code is running.
I've made sure that there is no EOF with the command `eof $fh`.

When I perform this manually, I get (password, user & ip address are fictitious):

```
$ sshpass -p abcdef ssh root@1.2.3.4
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-45-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Thu Apr  3 11:22:33 2014 from 5.6.7.8
root@MyPC:~#
```

Please note: I know that there are other methods to perform this (Expect, keys), but I must understand why this specific method doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Line buffering when output not going to a terminal?

Comment: @DonalFellows: Sorry but don't understand the question.

Comment: _Many_ programs change their buffering style when the output is going to a pipe or a file instead of a terminal. I don't know if that's true here. (If you're just running a single remote command, you might not need to care.)

Comment: The only command that I'm running is `sshpass`, and through it I want to execute many commands on the remote machine. Currently, I didn't even reach the prompt, so I can't run any command on the remote machine. You wrote "I don't know if that's true here" - how should I test? Do you mean to the program `sshpass` or other program?

Comment: @DonalFellows: Is this relevant: http://blog.ipspace.net/2007/10/you-cannot-start-telnet-session-from.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code against one of my servers, Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, and I got no login message at all.

Then I added a `puts $fh "ls -l"` after fconfigure, and the file listing came after message "iteration 2".

So your problem is just different behavior of ssh depending on the call environment.

There is nothing wrong, and it makes sense: you would normally not want the login headlines in a script called ssh, but just the command output.

I did not work through the extensive config and command line options, though. And I don't have sshpass on my machine, I just used ssh with authentication by ssh-agent.

Btw, write the catch like that:

```
if {[catch {mycommand param1} catchres]} then {
  puts stderr $catchres
} else {
  # no error, contine
}
```